# Scraping AngularJS using Selenium

Tags: python, angularjs, web-scraping

I'm looking for a method to retrieve certain info from this URL:

http://www.mediadata.it/it/aziende-comunicatori/elenco/%7B%7D/1

After a lot of googling and browsing this site I have figured out a way to do so:
I have downloaded Selenium, added gecko to the path, and avoided the bug with the latest version of Firefox.

I am looking for this:

```
<h5 class="ng-binding">A.I.O.P. - ASS. ITALIANA OSPEDALITA' PRIVATA</h5>
```

And this:

```
<h5 class="ng-binding">10 CORSO COMO - GALLERIA CARLA SOZZANI</h5>
```

I read I have to understand where the site takes the information and how is asked the request to try to fake it and letting the server give me the dynamic information - it's beyond me.

I suppose this part of the code is right since I took it from another question and it doesn't give any errors:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.mediadata.it/it/aziende-
comunicatori/elenco/%7B%7D/1")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

It works fine and handles the request in the right way, but I am definitely unable to retrieve the unsorted list elements with this:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ng-binding")))

links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.ng-binding  h5")]
print(links)

driver.close()
```

I am not looking into someone who will write it for me. I need to understand how to think to figure out the solution!